# How does AOP help in data binding?

Tags: .net, data-binding, aop

I recently read an [interesting blog post](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/AOP-in-C-Over-Anders-Hejlsberge28099s-Dead-Body!.aspx) on Anders Hejlsberg's arguments against AOP.

The first anti-anti argument mentions data binding:

> Myth 1. “Aspect-oriented programming is interesting for debugging and instrumentation of code and is not a full-fledged programming discipline.”
>
> Truth 1. Anders probably stopped at the “Hello, world” example.
>
> Although code instrumentation is certainly an important use case of AOP – and the one you would see in every “getting started” documentation – the technology significantly simplifies the work of developers when it comes to implement any non-trivial, real-life application. Just to cite a few real-life scenarios where AOP really helps:

```
* Data Binding (INotifyPropertyChanged)
```

I'm trying to think of how AOP is used in a data binding scenario.  I always assumed that binding relied on reflection to do it's "magic."  I'm pretty sure everything you need in a binding scenario is available via reflection.  Is AOP being used for a (slight) performance boost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the databinding he's referring to, but the `INotifyPropertyChanged` (and similar) part that AOP would really shine.

Currently, when a class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, properties look like this:

```
private bool _isSomeProperty;
public bool IsSomeProperty
{
  get{ return _isSomeProperty;}
  set
  { 
    if( value != _isSomeProperty)
    {
      _isSomeProperty = value;
      OnNotifyPropertyChanged( "IsSomeProperty");
    }
  }
}
```

Where with decent AOP, they could look like this

```
[NotifyOnChange]    
public bool IsSomeProperty {get; set;}
```

Makes a big readability difference, especially when the setter for a couple properties has a few actual rules in it.

Even with generic base classes, Expressions, Reflection, and some tricky implementations, the best you hope for is:

```
private bool _isSomeProperty;
public bool IsSomeProperty
{
  get{ return _isSomeProperty;}
  set
  { 
    SetAndNotify( x=>x.IsSomeProperty)
  }
}
```

And even that's not as readable (and is less performant as well)

Comment: Great answer.  I don't code in WPF much, so when I think Data Binding, I think ASP.NET, and I think one way read only(in which reflection would be perfectly fine).  Thanks.